# Distribute Days Between Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like such:

```
LeaveRequestID | DateAllocated    | DateFrom    | DateTo     | TotalLeaveDays
1              |  2020-03-02      | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-05 |  3
2              |  2020-03-02      | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-04 |  2
```

And here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.DateAllocated,
    t2.DateFrom,
    t2.DateTo,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, t2.DateFrom, t2.DateTo) TotalLeaveDays 
FROM 
    tblLeave_Allocation t1
INNER JOIN 
    tblLeave_Requests t2 ON CONVERT(VARCHAR, t1.DateAllocated, 23) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, t2.DateFrom, 23)
```

Here is my desired output:

```
LeaveRequestID  | DateAllocated | DateFrom    | DateTo     | TotalLeaveDays | DateDist   | LeaveCount
1               | 2020-03-02    | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-05 |    3           | 2020-03-03 | 1
1               | 2020-03-02    | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-05 |    3           | 2020-03-04 | 1
1               | 2020-03-02    | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-05 |    3           | 2020-03-05 | 1
2               | 2020-03-02    | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-04 |    2           | 2020-03-03 | 1
2               | 2020-03-02    | 2020-03-02  | 2020-03-04 |    2           | 2020-03-04 | 1
```

I would like to distribute every count of single `TotalLeaveDays` for each count starting from a day after `DateFrom` until `DateTo`. How to achieve my desired output?

Comment: FYI your link should be `JOIN tblLeave_Requests t2 ON DateAllocated =  t2.DateFrom` converting dates to strings before joining will slow you down a lot.

Comment: I did that to exclude the time when I'm joining the dates. Will your query disregard the `time` on `datetime`?

Comment: no it won't, in that case you should cast to DATE type not varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive CTE seems well suited for this:

```
with cte as (
      select LeaveRequestID, DateAllocated, DateFrom, DateTo, TotalLeaveDays,
             1 as n, dateadd(day, 1, datefrom) as datedist
      from t
      union all
      select LeaveRequestID, DateAllocated, DateFrom, DateTo, TotalLeaveDays,
             n + 1, dateadd(day, 1, datedist) as datedist
      from cte
      where n < TotalLeaveDays
     )
select LeaveRequestID, DateAllocated, DateFrom, DateTo, TotalLeaveDays, datedist, 1
from cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating/using a calendar table and then joining it to our current result. In **SQL Server**, you can use the following steps:

**Creating the calendar table (If you already don't have one):**

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20200101',
        @MaxDate DATE = '20210101';

SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
INTO #Calendar
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;
```

**Creating Sample Current Output:**

```
select a.*
into #tableA
from
(select 1 as LeaveRequestID,CAST('2020-03-02' as date) as DateAllocated,
        CAST('2020-03-02' as date) as DateFrom,CAST('2020-03-05' as date) as DateTo,
        3 as TotalLeaveDays union
 select 2 as LeaveRequestID,CAST('2020-03-02' as date) as DateAllocated,
        CAST('2020-03-02' as date) as DateFrom,CAST('2020-03-04' as date) as DateTo,
        2 as TotalLeaveDays) a
```

**Performing the join to get the desired output:**

```
select a.*,
       b.[date] as DateDist 
from #tableA a
left join #Calendar b
on b.[date] between DATEADD(d,1,a.Datefrom) and a.DateTo
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option which uses an ad-hoc tally/numbers table

**Example**

```
Select A.* 
      ,DateDist = dateadd(DAY,N,DateFrom)
 From  YourTable A
 Join (
         Select Top 10000 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
          From  master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
      ) B on N<=TotalLeaveDays
 Order By LeaveRequestID,N
```

**Returns**

```
LeaveRequestID  DateAllocated   DateFrom    DateTo      TotalLeaveDays  DateDist
1               2020-03-02      2020-03-02  2020-03-05  3               2020-03-03
1               2020-03-02      2020-03-02  2020-03-05  3               2020-03-04
1               2020-03-02      2020-03-02  2020-03-05  3               2020-03-05
2               2020-03-02      2020-03-02  2020-03-04  2               2020-03-03
2               2020-03-02      2020-03-02  2020-03-04  2               2020-03-04
```